# How can I change styles of component in different places?

Tags: angular

I have  component, that is only used in app.component.html. This footer exists on all pages. I want to change background-color of it on  component. Styles of footer are in footer.component.css. So how can I do it?

Comment: You can always just set the `background-color` on the `footer.component.css` file. Could you clarify your question: Do you want to change the `background-color` according to the page?

Answer (score 1):

On footer.component.css you have the original color.

If you use the footer (component name: my-footer) on app.component like this:

```
<my-footer></my-footer>
```

You can add on app.component.css some css to override the original color

```
my-footer ... {
    background-color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need say to Angular that the page has change and make some when this change happens. One method is subscribe to router.event. So, imagine you has a app.component like

```
<div class="container">
    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
       routerLink="/one">One</a> |

    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
       routerLink="/two">Two</a> | 

    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
      routerLink="/three">three</a> 

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer [style.background-color]="color"></footer>
  </div>
```

In ngOnInit of the component you can subscribe, so

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.router.events.pipe(filter(event=>event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      switch (res.url)
      {
         case "/one":
            this.color="orange"
            break;
         case "/two":
            this.color="pink"
            break;
         case "/three":
            this.color="silver"
            break;
      }
    })
  }
```

You can see an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8eiqc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

NOTE: In this case use [style.background-color], you can use also [ngClass] and change the subscription to give a different class

**Updated** if you don't want figth with paths, always can create a service

```
export class BkService {
  private colorSubject=new Subject<any>()
  colorObservable=this.colorSubject.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  setColor(color:any)
  {
    this.colorSubject.next(color);
  }
}
```

Then you can subscribe in the ngOnInit of app.component

```
this.bkService.colorObservable.subscribe(res=>{
  this.borderColor=res;
})
```

Each component, in ngOnInit you can do, e.g.

```
constructor(private bkService:BkService){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.bkService.setColor('red');
  }
```

**Edited 2**
Using a service, you can use a simple variable too

In app.component

```
  get fontSize()
  {
    return this.bkService.fontSize;
  }
```

And in each component

```
this.bkService.fontSize=".5rem"
```