# Changing footer background colour on route change in Angular

Tags: angular

There's a footer component, the first two lines of which look like this:

**footer.html**

```
<footer class="footer" [class.footer_bg-white]="wide">
  <div class="footer__inner" [class.footer__inner_wide]="wide [class.footer__inner_auth]="!authorized">
```

and as we see, the background becomes white when the `wide` parameter is equal to `true`. I've implemented one more component, namely, one more page that user may go to with the help of the menu and the requirements are to make the footer background for this page white. I know it's far from being the best solution but as far as I understand that logic is pretty general so it seems fine to modify the footer.html in the following way:

**footer.html**

```
<footer class="footer" [class.footer_bg-white]="wide || isOffer">
  <div class="footer__inner" [class.footer__inner_wide]="wide [class.footer__inner_auth]="!authorized">
```

so when `wide` is `false` but we're on the Offer page `isOffer` is set to `true` and the footer should turn white. The part responsible for this in the `footer.ts` file looks as follows:

**footer.ts**

```
 ngOnChanges() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(
      event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart && event.url === "/offer") {
          this.isOffer = true;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

The problem with this is that when I open the menu and go to that page, the route changes and `isOffer` becomes `true` but the footer background color does not change, I need to reload the page for the changes to be applied. So it looks like this way I have to recreate the footer component once more.

How do I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) instead of directly changing the HTML element's class.

Comment: @Nikhil You mean like this? `[ngClass]="{'footer_bg-white': isSpecial}"`, if I do this, the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: Also change other elements to use `NgClass`. Make sure you are using `isSpecial` everywhere, looks like you renamed it from `isOffer`.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I accidentally renamed it. I've changed it to `[ngClass]="{'footer_bg-white': wide || isOffer}" ` but ut didn't change anything in terms of behaviour, it's still the same. It does look to me that I have to somehow reload the component, I mean the footer component but I have to do this programmatically. But I'm not sure...

Comment: @igor can you try replacing `ngOnChanges` with `ngOnInit` in `footer.ts`?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan yeah, I've just tried it and it didn't work..

Comment: @KarthickManoharan nope, it didn't work.

Comment: @igor Can you create a demo and share with stackblitz?

Comment: @igor Are you having the `footer` in all your components?. If so `subscribing` to router changes will not work.

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I'm afraid creating a working demo won't be easy. Yeah the footer is present in all components. Why? And do you have any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: @igor Ideally i wouldn't keep the footer inside the component. I have provided a solution

Comment: why you include "footer" in all components? I think that another aproach is include the footer in the main.component and subscribe to router.events in the main.component. some like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714203/how-can-i-change-styles-of-component-in-different-places/57717160#57717160

Comment: @Eliseo well yeah I screwed up explaining it, I mean indeed it's a separate component, but it's present on all pages, I need it in different colors. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Initial router change will not captured since you have the `footer` inside the component. You have to get the current router path to make it work.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.router.url === "/offer") {
    this.isOffer = true;
  }
}
```