# Reuse common layout for different pages How to hide and show piece of layout depending upon the page in angular

Tags: angular

In my application am resuing the header,sidebar and footer  for different pages.Can anybdoy tell how to show and hide piece of layout depend on the page

Thanks

Comment: It's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714203/how-can-i-change-styles-of-component-in-different-places/57717160#57717160

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive, to show and hide parts of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Create a configuration service. Subscribe router event in the root component. Change the configuration according to route. Bind components existence to that configuration service (or object) using NgIf. Note that this should be done in a component that declares the components will be manipulated. If you have multiple containers you can share that service.