# How to change the opacity of an angular component from another component in the router-outlet?

Tags: angular

I have a router outlet in my app.component and a nav-bar component which looks like this:-

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<router-outlet (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></router-outlet>
```

I have a component called home-component from which I want to change the opacity of the nav-bar component as and when required. The app-routing.module:-

```
    import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    ]
```

I have seen some examples where a variable is passed from child to parent component etc. But what I'm using is a route is it possible to do it here or should a service be used?

Comment: Please provide Stackblitz code.

Comment: Since your nav-bar is global, and the other component isn't really a child, a singleton service would be a good choice here. A service with a BehaviorSubject set by "setOpacity()" method, and then in your nav-bar, call "getOpacity()" which should return the said BehaviourSubject as an Observable.

Comment: Yes, you need use a service or subscribe to router event, not use a "event" in router-outlet. Perhafs this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714203/how-can-i-change-styles-of-component-in-different-places/57717160#57717160 can help you