# how to exclude footer from a specific page

Tags: angular

I am using angular version 14. I have a page where footer is showing. But I want to hide the footer from that page. It is a job search page, and I want to hide or remove footer from job search page. I just don't want footer here. Footer I have declared separately in website.component.html

job page data.service.ts code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { urls } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private baseUrl = `${urls.BaseUrl}`;
    private data = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([{fetching: true}]);
    data$ = this.data.asObservable();

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    updateSource(newData: any) {
        this.data.next(newData);
    }

    updateItem(item: any, index: number): void {
        this.data.getValue()[index] = item;
    }

    addItem(item: any): void {
        this.data.getValue().push(item);
    }

    getItem(index: number) {
        return this.data.getValue()[index];
    }

    deleteItem(index: number) {
        const afterDel: any = [];
        this.data.getValue().forEach( (item: any, i: number) => {
            if (i !== index) {
                afterDel.push(item);
            }
        })
        this.updateSource(afterDel);
    }

    save(params: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/job-question`;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
    }

    saveReplay(params: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/job-question-replay`;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
    }

    saveOffer(params: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/job-offer`;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
    }

    update(params: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/update`;

        return this.http.put<any>(url, params);
    }

    delete(index: number): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/delete/${this.getItem(index).id}`;

        return this.http.delete<any>(url);
    }

    list(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }

    getJobPost(id: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job/${id}`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }

    addReport(params: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/job-report`;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
    }

    // Filters
    priceHighLow(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list-price-high-low`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }
    priceLowHigh(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list-price-low-high`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }
    dueDateEarly(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list-price-due-dateearliest`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }
    dueDateLast(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list-price-due-datelast`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }
    oldTask(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list-old-task`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }
    clostToMe(): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/get-job-list-closest-to-me`;

        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }
    toBeDone(params: any) : Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/to-be-done`;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
    }
    withdrawOffer(params: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/withdraw-offer`;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
    }

}
```

job page component.ts code

```
import { ApiService } from './../../servies/api.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { urls } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchTask',
  templateUrl: './searchTask.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchTask.component.scss'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class SearchTaskComponent implements OnInit {
  defultUser : any = 'assets/img/avatar_men.png'
  modalRef?:BsModalRef;

  jobList : any;
  card_show = false;
  ImageUrl = urls.BaseUrl;
  currentUserId : any;
  alreadyOffered = false;

  withdrawOffer : any;
  deletingIndex = -1;
  deletePop: any;

  postTime : any;
  status: boolean = false;

  selectJobPostData : any;
  offerText : string = '';
  selectedPostId : number = 0;
  offerAmount : any;
  offerNote : string = '';
  activeClass: boolean = false;

  searchText : any = '';

  lat = -33.8482439;
  long = 150.9319747;
  zoom=10;
  markers : any
  url : any;

  reportNote = '';
  questionId = -1;
  questionIndex = -1;
  replaytext = '';

  isPoster : boolean = false;
  searchTextId :any = '';
  imageulr : any;

  toBeDone : any = '';

  offerSubmited = false;
  
  constructor(private ds: DataService,
              private api : ApiService,
              private ts: ToastrService,
              private ms: BsModalService,
              public router: Router,
              private route : ActivatedRoute) {
                this.isPoster = this.api.isPoster();
                this.imageulr = urls.BaseUrl + '/getjobpostimage/'
  }

  setToBeDone(val : string) : void {
    this.toBeDone = val;
  }
  
  config = {
    backdrop: true,
    ignoreBackdropClick: true
  };

  openModalReport(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.ms.show(template, this.config);
  }

  openModalReportOne(template: TemplateRef<any>, id : any = -1, index : any = -1) {
    this.questionId = id;
    this.questionIndex = index;
    this.modalRef = this.ms.show(template, this.config);
  }

  dismiseModal() : void {
    this.modalRef?.hide();
  }

  addReport() : void {
    let obj = {
      job_post_id : this.selectedPostId,
      detail : this.reportNote
    };

    this.ds.addReport(obj).subscribe((resp:any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.ts.success(resp.msg);
        this.modalRef?.hide();
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ds.list().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });

        //this.searchText = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('title');
        this.searchTextId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
        //String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('title'));
        //this.searchText = (cat == null) ? cat : '';

        if (this.searchTextId) {
          this.selectJobPost(this.searchTextId);
        }
        

      }
    });
    if (this.api.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.currentUserId = this.api.getRegUser().id;
    } 
  }

  search() : void {
    if (this.searchText != '') {
      this.jobList = this.jobList.filter((i:any) => i.what_do_you == this.searchText);
    }
  }

  selectJobPostFeatch(id:any,what_do_you:any) : void { 
    this.selectJobPost(id);
    var title = what_do_you.replace(/\s/g,'-'); 
    //console.log(a)
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/search-job/'+title+'/'+id);
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass; 
    // if (this.searchText != '') {
    //   this.jobList = this.jobList.filter((i:any) => i.what_do_you == this.searchText);
    // }
  }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.ms.show(template, Object.assign({}, { class: 'modal-lg modal-dialog-centered' }));
  }

  openModal2(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.ms.show(template, Object.assign({}, { class: 'modal-sm modal-dialog-centered' }));
  }

  selectJobPost(id : any) : void {
    
    this.ds.getJobPost(id).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.alreadyOffered = false;
      if (resp.success) {
        this.selectedPostId = id;
        this.card_show = true;  
        this.selectJobPostData = resp.data;
        this.checkAlreadyOffer(resp.data.total_offer)
        this.timeDifferent(resp.data.created_at, new Date());
      } else {
        this.ts.warning('There is something wrong, try again later');
      }
    })
  }

  checkAlreadyOffer(offers: any) : void {
    offers.forEach((e: any) => {
      if (e.offer_by_id == this.currentUserId) {
        this.alreadyOffered = true;
      }      
    });
  }

  timeDifferent(start_date: any, end_date:any) : any {
    var date1 = new Date(start_date); 
      var date2 = new Date(end_date);    

    let Time : number = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
    let days : any = Math.floor(Time / 86400000);
    let hour : any = Math.floor((Time % 86400000) / 3600000);
    let mint : any = Math.round(((Time % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
    
    this.postTime = ((days != 0) ? days + ' : ' : '') + ((hour != 0) ? hour + ' : ' : '') + ((mint != 0) ? mint : '');
    
  }

  closeJobPost() : void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/search-job');
    this.card_show = false;
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass; 
  }

  saveOffer() : void {
    this.offerSubmited = true
    if (this.offerAmount < 1) {
      this.ts.warning('Enter some budget to submit the offer'); 
    }
    if (this.offerNote == ''){
      this.ts.warning('Enter your bid description!');  
    }
    else {
      if (this.api.isAuthenticated()) {
      let postData = {
        job_post_id : this.selectedPostId,
        amount : this.offerAmount,
        detail : this.offerNote
      };

      this.ds.saveOffer(postData).subscribe((resp: any) => { 
        if (resp.success) {
          this.alreadyOffered = true;
          this.ds.getJobPost(this.selectedPostId).subscribe((resp: any) => {
            if (resp.success) {
              this.selectedPostId = this.selectedPostId;
              this.card_show = true;  
              this.selectJobPostData = resp.data;
              this.checkAlreadyOffer(resp.data.total_offer)
              this.timeDifferent(resp.data.created_at, new Date());
            } 
          })
          //selectedData[0].total_offer.push(resp.data);
          this.modalRef?.hide();
          this.offerAmount = 0;
          this.ts.success('The offer submited successfully');
          //window.location.reload();
        } else {
          this.ts.warning('There is something wrong, please try again later');
        }
      });
    }else{
      this.modalRef?.hide();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/register/tasker');
    }
  }
  }

  saveQuestion() : void {
    if (this.offerText.trim() == '') {
      this.ts.warning('Enter some text to submit the question');
    } else {
      let postData = {
        job_post_id : this.selectedPostId,
        detail : this.offerText
      };

      this.ds.save(postData).subscribe((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.success) {
          this.selectJobPostData.total_question.push(resp.data);
          this.offerText = '';
          this.ts.success('The question submited successfully');
        } else {
          this.ts.warning('There is something wrong, please try again later');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  updateQuestion() : void {
    if (this.replaytext.trim() == '') {
      this.ts.warning('Enter some text to submit the reply');
    } else {
      let postData = {
        id : this.questionId,
        replay : this.replaytext
      };

      this.ds.saveReplay(postData).subscribe((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.success) {
          console.log(this.selectJobPostData.total_question[this.questionIndex]);
          
          this.selectJobPostData.total_question = resp.data;
          this.replaytext = '';
          this.questionId = -1;
          this.questionIndex = -1;
          this.ts.success('The question submited successfully');
          this.modalRef?.hide();
        } else {
          this.ts.warning('There is something wrong, please try again later');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  getToBeDone() {
    let obj = {
      tobedone : this.toBeDone
    }
    this.ds.toBeDone(obj).subscribe((resp:any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }

  // Filters
  priceHightToLow() : void {
    this.ds.priceHighLow().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  priceLowToHigh() : void {
    this.ds.priceLowHigh().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  dueDateEarly() : void {
    this.ds.dueDateEarly().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  dueDateLast() : void {
    this.ds.dueDateLast().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  newTask() : void {
    this.ds.list().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  oldTask() : void {
    this.ds.oldTask().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  closeToMe() : void {
    this.ds.clostToMe().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success) {
        this.jobList = resp.data;
        this.url = urls.BaseUrl +'/getprofileimage/';
        this.markers = [];
        this.jobList.forEach((post: any) => {
          if (post.place_id != null) {          
            let mark = {
              lat : post.lat,
              lng : post.lng,
              label : post.where_do_you
            };
            this.markers.push(mark);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
}

handleImgError(ev: any){
  let source = ev.srcElement;
  source.src = this.defultUser;
}

Offerwithdraw() : void {
  let obj = {
    job_post_id : this.selectedPostId,
    offer_by_id : this.currentUserId
  };
  this.ds.withdrawOffer(obj).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    if (resp.success) {
      this.selectJobPostData = resp.data;  
      this.alreadyOffered = false;
      this.offerAmount = '';
      this.offerNote = '';
      this.modalRef?.hide();      
    } else {
      this.ts.warning('There is something wrong happen try again later');
    }
  })
}

}
```

job page module.ts code

```
import { GoogleMapApi } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { SharedModule } from './../../shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SearchTaskComponent } from './searchTask.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: GoogleMapApi.apikey,
      libraries: ['places']
    }),
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: SearchTaskComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [SearchTaskComponent]
})
export class SearchTaskModule { }
```

jobpage.html code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark py-1 search_job_nav" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : 'notActive'">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="clickEvent()"> 
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
<ng-template #report>
    <div class="modal-body text-center p-5">
  
      <div id="">
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="reportNote"></textarea>
        </div>
  
      </div>
  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-3 ml-3" (click)="addReport()">Add</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" (click)="modalRef?.hide()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Website.component.html code

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


<!-- ======= Footer ======= -->
<footer id="footer" class="footer mt-5" *ngIf="setting_data">
  <div class="footer-top">
    <div class="container top-footer">
      <div class="row gy-4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 footer-info">
          <h4>Who are JobTasker?</h4>
          <p align="justify">JobTasker pty ltd (ABN-81650838823) is a Sydney based online platform that connect people who need to get ‘service’ jobs/tasks done to people or tradies (including small business) capable of getting their jobs/tasks done within budget. </p>
          <p align="justify">Also, providing a platform for people, tradies, and business to earn more by performing jobs/tasks posted on jobtasker. Service jobs/tasks such as cleaning, home relocation, delivery, labour, lawn mowing, handyman, plumbing, painting, rubbish removals, dog walking, fitness coach, photography, website dev., admin jobs and a lot more.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 footer-links">
          <h4>Company</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/about-us">About us</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/faqs">Help & FAQs</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy policy</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/terms-conditions">Terms and conditions</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/contact-us">Contact us</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 footer-links">
          <h4>Resources</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/post-task">Post a Job/task</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/how-it-works" >How It Works</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/be-a-tasker" >Be a Tasker</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="popular_categories" >Popular Categories</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/search-job" >Search Jobs/Tasks</a></li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> <a href="/blogs" >Blog and Articles</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i> {{setting_data.address? setting_data.address:''}}
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="d-flex footer-contact text-center text-md-start">
            <img src="../../assets/img/app-store.png" class="img-fluid" width="100px" />
          </div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="social-links my-3">
            <a [href]="setting_data.twitter? setting_data.twitter:'#'" class="twitter"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
            <a [href]="setting_data.facebook? setting_data.facebook:'#'"  class="facebook"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
            <a [href]="setting_data.instagram? setting_data.instagram:'#'"  class="instagram"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
            <a [href]="setting_data.linkedin? setting_data.linkedin:'#'"  class="linkedin"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
            <!-- <a [href]="setting_data.linkedin? setting_data.linkedin:'#'"  class="youtube"><i class="bi bi-youtube"></i></a> -->
            <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@jobtasker"  class="tiktok"><i class="bi bi-tiktok"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container last-footer">
      <div class="col-12  copyright">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- <div class=" col-lg-4  col-md-12       text-left ">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.jobtasker.au/assets/img/white-logo.png" width="150" /></a>
                </div> -->
          <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="#" class="text-white"><strong><span>{{setting_data.site_footer? setting_data.site_footer:''}}</span></strong></a>

            <a href="" style="margin-left: 10px;"><strong> All Right Reserved</strong></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</footer><!-- End Footer -->
<a href="#" class="back-to-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i
    class="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>
```

Comment: The *ngIf is fine. Can you show the logic for the .ts part about setting_data property

Comment: updated the question. Pasted the component.ts code

Comment: also pasted data.service.ts code

Answer (score 0):

In this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714203/how-can-i-change-styles-of-component-in-different-places/57717160#57717160) use two approach: check about router path or use a service to change the background-color and border. You can use a similar idea to give value to a variable and use a `*ngIf`

Using an observable you even can do

```
 this.showFooter$=this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event=>event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      ,map((res:any)=>res.url!="/your-path not show footer"))
```

and use

```
<footer *ngIf="showFooter$|async">footer</footer>
```